# python cmd error: invalid command 'y'

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line, cython, sys

Python - When parsing the following command-line arguments...

`sys.argv = ('%s %s build_ext --inplace' % ('python', sys.argv[0]))`

...for Cython inside my buildscript "myscript_pyd_setup.py" for "myscript.pyd" that uses the "myscript.py" file I get the following error (e1):

> python error 1: invalid command 'y'

The python [command-line option](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html) `python -- help` revealed no corresponding option 'y'. This makes sense otherwise the error would not exist. Searching SO, Python docs and the web resulted in unrelated articles about `Tkinter`. As I do absolutely nothing with Tkinter, as far as I know it, I'm wondering if this error is from the python command-line interpreter at all?

My effort:

What I tried to accomplish is parsing arguments `sys.argv.append('build_ext --inplace')` to python command-line interpreter when running the "buildscript" from within the editor (Komodo edit 11.x) but it returns also with an error (e2) similar to the version from command-line or another editor.

> python error 2: invalid command name 'build_ext --inplace'

Running "myscript_pyd_setup.py" with `sys.argv.append('build_ext')` builds the required *.pyd file just fine. What I don't understand is why its choking on `--infile`. This works for `py2exe` and `pyinstaller`.

The objective:

To run the setup-script of "myscript.py" from within the editor and not having to flip back-and-forth to the command-line editor for compiling *.py > *.pyd when I changed code inside "myscript.py" and want to see the result quickly.

> **Note**: parsing command-line `python myscript_pyd_setup.py build_ext --inplace` works fine when `sys.argv...` is commented-out in the "buildscript"!

A third option was to use `cythonize` in combo with the "myscript.py" and "myscript.pyd" files but that showed a copyfile error for "myscript.pyd". Relevant but not for the above asked "error = y" question.

Any thoughts and help on how to automate this part to prevent RSI are more than welcome! Thx.

My "myscript.py" example code:

```
import sys, time, os

#...snippet...

def print_me():
    text = "bar(man), yes, Hello, how do you do Mr. foo?"
    return text

if __name__ == '__main__':

    #...snippet...

    print_me()
```

The myscript_pyd_setup.py:

```
# myscript.py

try:
    from setuptools import setup
    from setuptools import Extension
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup
    from distutils.extension import Extension

from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
#from Cython.Build import cythonize
import sys

print 'sys.argv[0] : %s' % sys.argv[0]

#sys.argv = ('%s %s build_ext --inplace' % ('python', sys.argv[0]))

sys.argv.append('build_ext --inplace')

ext_modules = [Extension("myscript",['myscript.py'])]
#ext_modules = cythonize("myscript.py")

#setup: "name" and "cmdclass" are commented-out when using cythonize.

setup(
    name= 'XYZ model class',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    include_dirs = [],
    ext_modules = ext_modules)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sys.argv` is a list of arguments. When you append `'build_ext --inplace'`, you literally append that as a single argument (as if you've passed it enclosed in quotes from the shell command line). That is what happened in the second case.

In the first one, you've assigned string back to `sys.argv`. But string is also a sequence, so your commands ran as if called with (`argv[1:]`): `` ['y', 't', `h`, ...] ``

In either case you ended up with an option/sub-command unknown the the argument parser.

Comment: If I understand you correctly it should be `sys.argv.append('build', '--inplace')` command? Because if its first `'build'` followed by the second append `'--inplace'` the first command will be executed without the latter...

Comment: Actually: `sys.argv.append('build'); sys.argv.append('--inplace')` or `sys.argv.extend(('build', '--inplace'))`.
`sys.argv.append('build', '--inplace')` wouldn't work at all, because `append` method takes a single argument and appends a single item.

Comment: A generic comment. I hope these prove to be useful to help you advance, but it only addresses your immediate problem. 

I am not too wild about the `sys.argv` manipulation for it is a global attribute of the running environment and doing so violates interface/object encapsulation (it is not neat and possibly causes trouble down the road). Unfortunately I am not familiar enough with `distutils` to give you the correct answer off the bet, but I would encourage you to look around and see how to pass you own set of arguments replacing use of `sys.argv` (`argparse` for instance allows the same).

Comment: Cheers for that... I'll look into it. When I've got it covered I'll let you know how I solved it.